# Create a post with many-to-many relationship in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a structure very much for between category and yell. What I do is qeuro a call on POST type API with the following parameters:

```
{
    "user_id":"1",
    "title":"primeito",
    "desciption":"de_novo",
    "categories":[{"name":"eletro"},{"name":"domestic"},{"name":"new_category"}],
    "yell_type":"novo",
    "price":"10,00",
    "payment_type":"boleto"
}
```

My structure is as follows:

My model yell:

```
#yell.rb
class Yell < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :yells
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

model category:

```
#category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :yells
end
```

method crete in controller yell:

```
#yells_controller.rb
def create
@yell = Yell.new(yell_params)

params[:categories].each do |rel|
  @category = Category.find_by_name(rel[:name])
  if @category
    #only creates the relationship
  else
    @yell.categories.build(name: rel[:name]) #creates the relationship and category
  end
end

if @yell.save
     render json: @yell, status: :created, location: api_yell_path(@yell)
   else
     render json: @yell.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
   end
end
...
private:

    def yell_params
      params.require(:yell).permit(:title, :desciption, :price, :payment_type, :user_id, :yell_type, :categories)
    end
```

So I created the table

```
class CreateCategoriesYellsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :categories_yells, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :category_id
      t.integer :yell_id
    end

    add_index :categories_yells, [:category_id, :yell_id]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :categories_yells
  end
end
```

I can make him create the categories, but does not know how to create only the relationship. Agluem can help me is the comment #only creates the relationship?

I need to do this check because the category name is unique

Also if someone know something more elegant way to do this, I accept suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do so I had to create a model to join my table:

model category_yell.rb

```
class CategoriesYell < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :yell
end
```

and `create` my method was as follows:

```
def create
  #@yell = Yell.new(yell_params.except(:categories))
  @yell = Yell.new({title: params[:title], desciption: params[:desciption], price: params[:price], user_id: params[:user_id], yell_type: params[:yell_type]})

  if @yell.save
    Array(params[:categories]).each do |rel|

      @category = Category.find_by_name(rel[:name])

      if @category
        @categories_yells = CategoriesYell.new(category_id: @category.id, yell_id: @yell.id)

        if @categories_yells.save
          @yell.categories.build(id: @category.id, name: rel[:name])#only creates the relationship
        else
          render json: {status: 1, message:"relationship categoy not create", data: @yell.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end

      else
        @yell.categories.create(name: rel[:name]) #creates the relationship and category
      end

    end

    render json: {status: 0, message:"sucess", data: @yell}, status: :created
  else
    render json: {status: -1, message:"error", data: @yell.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understood the last paragraph, but I think you need an intermediate table to join the two models first.

You would need to create a table like this:

```
class CreateCategoriesAndYells < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories_yells, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :category, index: true
      t.belongs_to :yell, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Then you would need to update your controller to say something like this:

```
@yell.categories.build(category_params)
```

You would need also to pass the category parameters to the controller.

Comment: Then, the table I had created, what was missing was the @ yell.categories.build (category_params), but I still have one doubt: to call this method, if there is a category it will be created? And if there is it only creates the relationship without creating a new one?